# Странная ошибка в логах сервера Apache

Tags: apache

Просматриваю логи ошибок сервера Apache и нашел там очень странную ошибку, которую раньше никогда не встречал:

**[Wed Jan 29 11:38:05.420588 2014] [core:error] [pid 4500] [client 86.57.255.92:20043] AH00126: Invalid URI in request \xa3{(i\xc0\xb2hy\xa4\x84\xba\bq/\b7\x0c\xfcV\xbe**

Что может означать эта ошибка? Как ее можно пофиксить?

Comment: насколько я знаю, это обычно значит, что разные боты пытаются потестить различные уязвимости на Вашем апаче. цель - заставить апач выполнить произвольный код (к примеру - добавить левого пользователя, создать файл с кодом) либо просто уронить апач.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

{ - недопустимый в УРЛ символ. Пофиксить? Найти причину почему он там появляется или, если он необходим, то закодировать его (%7b). Но судя по URI, это какая-то попытка хакеров прощупать уязвимости вашего сайта, так что если сайт нормально обходит подобные попытки, то побалуются и забудут